# Outlook AppleScript copy attachments of one email to a newly created email

Tags: macos, email, outlook, applescript, email-attachments

I want to take any attachments of one email, create a new email and attach those attachments to the new email and send it.  Is there any way to do this without saving each attachment?

I have this:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    
    set theMessage to first item of (get current messages)
    set attFiles to attachments of theMessage
    --  set attfilesname to name of attFiles
    set fwdMessage to forward theMessage without opening window
    set forwardbody to content of fwdMessage
    set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:forwardsubject, content:forwardbody}
    make new recipient at newMessage with properties {email address:{address:forwardemailaddress}}
    repeat with thisatt in attFiles
        set fname to name of thisatt
        make new attachment with properties {file:fname} at the end of newMessage
    end repeat
    --make new attachment with properties {file:attfilesname} at the end of newMessage
    --  make new attachment at after the last word of the last paragraph with attFiles
    --  make new attachment at the end of newMessage with attFiles
    send newMessage
    
end tell
```

None of the tries above work.  The email gets sent without attachment(s).

Comment: Why don't you just forward the message?

Comment: I want to change the sender from one exchange account to another sender exchange account and I could not figure out how to change the sender account via AS on a forward.

Comment: I don't use outlook but much of the dictionary is similar to Mail. If you forward in AS, it should create an 'outgoing message', for which you should be able to set the sender or account — probably the latter for an exchange account.

Comment: As to re-using the attachments… `file` likely means a file specification, i.e. including path, and not merely a file name. I don't think you can avoid saving the attachments if you wish to reuse them. Of course, you could likely save them, attach them, send, delete them. Dunno but personally, I think forwarding will prove the simpler solution.